# Semantic UI Search Selection won't remain collapsed/unfocused on Modal load

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm using a [Semantic UI Search Selection](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-selection) and am using a very simple implementation of `.dropdown()` to convert static markup into a searchable country input.

The problem is that this input automatically focuses and the menu drops down on page load. If I wait until `$(window).load()`, I can remove the `active` and `visible` classes from the element (and its children), but I'd rather instantiate the menu without these to begin with.

My markup looks something like the following:

```js
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.css">
<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui form">
      <div class="field">
        <label>I am a:</label>
        <select class="ui dropdown" name="homeowner_type">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="Homeowner">Homeowner</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <!-- The dropdown in question -->
      <div class="field">
        <label>Country:</label>
        <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="country">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="us"><i class="us flag"></i>United States</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="uy"><i class="uy flag"></i>Uruguay</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="uz"><i class="uz flag"></i>Uzbekistan</div>
            <!-- additional countries -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are no other instances of `.dropdown()` in my code. Thoughts?

**EDIT:** I've discovered that this is happening because the form is included within a modal. The issue doesn't occur when the form is outside of the modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of April 2015, there is an undocumented Modal setting which is responsible for focusing the first `input` element contained within the Modal:

```
autofocus: function() {
    if(settings.autofocus) {
        var
            $inputs    = $module.find(':input:visible'),
            $autofocus = $inputs.filter('[autofocus]'),
            $input     = ($autofocus.length > 0)
                ? $autofocus
                : $inputs
        ;
        $input.first().focus();
    }
},
```

This setting is available to us under the `$.fn.modal.settings`. As a result, the following will prevent this search input from focusing when the Modal opens:

```
$('.ui.modal').modal({
    autofocus: false,
}).modal('show');
```

And a runnable example:

```js
$('.ui.modal').modal({
    autofocus: false,
}).modal('show');

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.css">
<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui form">
      <div class="field">
        <label>I am a:</label>
        <select class="ui dropdown" name="homeowner_type">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="Homeowner">Homeowner</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <!-- The dropdown in question -->
      <div class="field">
        <label>Country:</label>
        <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="country">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="us"><i class="us flag"></i>United States</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="uy"><i class="uy flag"></i>Uruguay</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="uz"><i class="uz flag"></i>Uzbekistan</div>
            <!-- additional countries -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had a dropdown list that popped up whenever my modal was loaded, scratched my head for days untill i found this answer. 
this fixed it `$('.ui.modal').modal({
    autofocus: false,
}).modal('show');`